# Deployment of tensorflow model which requires to get passed data for prediction normalized dependend on training statistics

Tags: tensorflow

The model trained in [TensorFlow tutorial "Regression: predict fuel efficiency"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression#make_predictions) can be stored with `model.save('basic_regression.h5')` and loaded/recovered with `model = keras.models.load_model('./basic_regression.h5')`. However the prediction

```
test_predictions = model.predict(normed_test_data).flatten()
```

requires normalized test data `normed_test_data`

```
def norm(x):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']
normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset)
normed_test_data = norm(test_dataset)
```

which depends on training statistics

```
train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
```

which are available during training only.

In case I would like to deploy a model like this I'd have to deploy the training statistics as well. Until now I assumed that a trained model including weights, etc. and stored as `.h5` file is sufficient to deploy a model into production. Have I missed something? Or is the tutorial incomplete/not suited as example for production ready models?